K4KQB was my call sign 70 years ago. Is it still valid?
K4KQB was my call sign 70 years ago. I had a general license
Is it still valid valid?

I still find articles about contests from 1975 done with that call sign! Also, the call sign K4KQB was formerly held by someone with the callsign W1YY. That might be you, or someone who held the callsign after you!
Anyways, the FCC is the authority keeping and assigning call signs for the USA (and yours is a US technician or general class call sign).
So, you need to look up your call sign in their register; that can be done here; click on "Amateur" on that website, then enter your callsign under "License Detail".
Doing that yields "no record".
If you don't renew your ham license, at some point you lose your callsign; that must be what has happened here.

the good news is that nobody else has been assigned your call sign; so you might be able to ask for it as so-called vanity callsign if you want to continue using it
the bad news is that your license lapsed, so you need to renew, which at this point might mean full re-examination (and thus a new assigned call sign). Afterwards, you can apply for your old callsign as vanity callsign.


Recent changes mean former license holders can bring proof of the former license/class (an old Callbook is sometimes sufficient) and the FCC will restore privileges if they pass the Technician exam. https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-47/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-97/subpart-F/section-97.505

As stated, you can apply for a vanity call as the prior holder of the call. This info from the ARRL is useful:

Request By Former Holder- The individual must hold a current license
and call sign before they may file an application for a vanity call
sign under the request by former holder provision to request a call
sign previously held by the licensee.  For other vanity call sign
types, see the instructions in the other sections.
Applying for the call sign
The vanity call sign application process is done directly through the
FCC. Applying for a vanity call sign online is very easy and should
take less than 5 minutes.
Apply online by logging into the license account in the FCC License
Manager filing system. In the License Manager section click on the
link that states “apply for vanity callsign”.
The individual will request the call sign(s) under the eligibility
“REQUEST BY FORMER HOLDER”.
For your primary station, you may request a call sign that was
previously assigned to your primary, secondary, repeater, auxiliary
link, control or space station. When so requesting for your primary
station:   You may request your former call sign even though it has
been unassigned for less than two years. The two-year requirement does
not apply to an otherwise eligible primary station if the call sign
was previously assigned to a station of the requestor You do not have
to hold a class of operator license required for the Group (A, B, C or
D) for the call sign requested. A call sign request by a former holder
may be from any Group in the sequential system. Your mailing address
does not have to be in the Region designated in the sequential system
for the call sign requested (excluding call signs for Regions 11-13).
A call sign requested by a close relative of a deceased former holder
may be in any Region. Retrieved from https://www.arrl.org/applying-for-a-vanity-call

You have to take a new technician test to get things started, then there is the question of proving you had the callsign previously. If you happen to have a copy of your old license, that is useful. If not, you can also use the callbook lookup service Hamcall.net offers an archiving search for members: https://www.hamcall.net/call?callsign=k4kqb.
I would suggest you make contact with a local Volunteer Examiner (VE) team and explain what you want to do. They can help you out. You can also contact the ARRL VEC office (vec@arrl.org) to help out if you cannot get a local team to lend a hand on the details.
Welcome back to the fold and best 73. -- Tom NY4I

It really depends on your local regulations, but callsigns are issued without a expiration date.

That's true for some licenses, but not for amateur radio licenses (which is 10 years),

The class operator permit class is indefinit, not the call sign, correct.
